# Problem with ViewVector

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to have a satellite (camera) move around the earth (unit sphere) and take picture of the earth. The satellite keeps constant distance from the earth, and always looks toward earth center.

```
Manipulate[ 
   Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], ViewVector -> {2*{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
   {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

This should produce the same size of circle no matter what angle `t` is being used, but the above code scales the images. I think I am not using `ViewVector` correctly here. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the option `SphericalRegion -> True` and specify a ViewAngle manually, e.g. `ViewAngle -> 70 Degree`.  I don't claim to have a full understanding of setting up views in 3D in Mathematica, so I won't comment on details ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem.

Comment: Maybe someone who actually understands why this works will come along and write a proper answer. ...

Comment: You can surround any code you post with backtick characters.  This not only gives prettier and more readable formatting, it also protects the code from being mangled (such as backslashes removed).

Comment: Actually, I think it does not work. I first thought it does, because the plain sphere does not have texture. However, once you put texture on, you will notice a discontinuity jump around t=1.57. Try this: `Manipulate[
  SphericalPlot3D[
   1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[CapitalPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]}, Mesh -> False, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
   ViewAngle -> 70/180*Pi, 
   ViewVector -> {2*{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {0, 0, 0}}], {t, 1.56, 1.58, 
   0.001}]`

Comment: I think this is because of the `ViewVertical` setting, which essentially controls the camera rotations around the `ViewVector`.  If you set a `ViewVertical` that never becomes parallel with the `ViewVector`, you'll see that the jump is not sudden any more but continuous.  This observation might be helpful for finding a good solution.

Comment: Do you really need the rotation to look vertical?  Could it look horizontal instead?  This wouldn't be an issue then. Alternatively you could `Rotate` the sphere itself instead of rotating the view.

Comment: What I really want to do is to create a 4-sided cube (with each side being of equal size) and move around it. I used sphere as a simplified example. I use the following code, but as you see, it scales the walls:

Comment: `Manipulate[
image=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}];
p1=Plot3D[y+1,{y,-1,0},{x,-1/2,1/2},PlotStyle->{Opacity[1],Texture[image]},Mesh->None,PlotRange->All];
p2=Plot3D[y-1,{y,0,1},{x,-1/2,1/2},PlotStyle->{Opacity[1],Texture[image]},Mesh->None,PlotRange->All];
p3=Plot3D[-y+1,{y,0,1},{x,-1/2,1/2},PlotStyle->{Opacity[1],Texture[image]},Mesh->None,
PlotRange->All];
p4=Plot3D[-y-1,{y,-1,0},{x,-1/2,1/2},
PlotStyle->{Opacity[1],Texture[image]},Mesh->None,
PlotRange->All];
Show[p1,p2,p3,p4,ViewVertical->{0,1,0},
ViewVector->{2000*{Cos[t],0,Sin[t]},{0,0,0}},
SphericalRegion->True],{t,0,2*Pi}]`

Comment: @Tim This is your "solid"![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CXUCB.png)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think kuba answer, although correct, really addresses the texture issue. `ViewVertical` is essential, but `ViewAngle` is not needed. Also, `SphericalRegion` helps.

```
Manipulate[
  SphericalPlot3D[1 , {u, 0, 180 °}, {v, 0, 360 °},
    Mesh -> None,
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5 - 1/2, 1 - #4} &), 
    PlotStyle -> Texture[satelliteImage],
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    Axes -> False,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    ViewVector -> {5*{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    ViewVertical -> {-Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}],
  {t, 0., 2.*Pi, Pi/18.}]
```

The `Manipulate` rotated a world globe about the y-axis like so

[image: globe]

where `satelliteImage` is this image

[image: world.map]

Comment: Is seems that one can fix `ViewAngle` or use `SphericalRegion`. But what's the difference at the end that you say I've missed the point?

Comment: No, not at all. But the OP was was looking for an answer that applied a texture. The problem he has with a discontinuity at the poles doesn't show up well with a simple graphic.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for comment. There were  no votes or comments, I was afraid I'm missing something again :p

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Szabolcs `ViewAngle` and `ViewVertical` is the answer. `SphericalRegion` is, in fact, redundant so I don't have to explain it (I can't ;P).

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], 
                      ViewVector -> {2*{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
                      ViewAngle -> Pi/2,
                      ViewVertical -> {-Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}]
          , {t, 0, 2*Pi, .3}]
```

`ViewVertical` is related with `ViewVector` by:

```
RotationTransform[-Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}][{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}]
```

> ```
> {-Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}
> ```

This fixes the problem of reorientation over the pole ;)

[image]

Is this what you are after?