# Rotate viewpoint around axis

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to know why I can't rotate this all the way around in a circle. The view flips rather than turning upside down, when trying to rotate about the Y-axis:

```
g = Graphics3D[{Blue, Cylinder[], Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 2}]}];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[g[[1]], 
  ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[i*2 \[Pi], {0, 1, 0}][{1, 0, 0}], 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ViewAngle -> Automatic], {i, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Confusingly, this approach works just fine for rotating around the Z-axis!

```
g = Graphics3D[{Blue, Cylinder[], Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 2}], Line[{{-2, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}, {-2, 0, 2}}]}];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[g[[1]], ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[i*2 \[Pi], {0, 0, 1}][{1, 0, 0}], SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewAngle -> Automatic], {i, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have to include the viewvertical here?

Comment: Closely related: [42314](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42314/5478)

Comment: It works for the z axis, but not the x or y...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `ViewVertical` in your transformation. Otherwise, the camera just flips around.

```
g = Graphics3D[{Blue, Cylinder[], Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 2}], Green, 
    Sphere[{2, 0, 2}, 0.1]}];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[g[[1]],
  ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[i*2 \[Pi], {0, 1, 0}][{1, 0, 0}],
  ViewVertical -> RotationTransform[i*2 \[Pi], {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, 1}],
  SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ViewAngle -> Automatic], {i, 0, 1}]
```

And it works for your second example because the up-direction of the camera is always correct since you are rotating around the z-axis